# Should an API controller attempt to catch all 500 internal server errors?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I apologize if this has been asked before, please link me to it. I am having a hard time finding discussion as to whether it is an acceptable practice to catch all internal server errors (500) in an API.

I have seen some arguments for it and some against it.
I've always heard that one should send a status instead of errors when possible. However, I do see how the 500 is semantically taking responsibility for a failed request and letting a client know that their request may not be at fault. But a status can convey that as well and then the 500 is just reserved for application container level errors not errors in the database or a class library.

Is there an accepted standard or is this an opinion topic?

e.g.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUserRoles()
{
    try
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, AuthorizationService.GetUserRoles());
    } 
    catch (SqlException sqle)
    {
        // log the exception
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "A data error occured. Contact IT Support.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log the exception
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "An error occured. Contact IT Support.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to always return the same structure

```
 public interface IResponse<T>
    {
        MsgType MsgType { get; }
        string Msg { get; }
        T Result { get; }
        string Origin { get; }
    }
```

---

Then you can have a *MasterApiController* with these methods

```
[NonAction]
public IHttpActionResult ResponseOk<T>(T result)
{
     return Ok<IResponse>(ResponseFactory.Create<T>(result, "", "Negocio"));
}

[NonAction]
public IHttpActionResult ResponseEx(Exception ex, string msg = "Un error ha ocurrido.")
{
     return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse<IResponse>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ResponseFactory.Create(msg, ex, "Negocio")));
}
```

---

And in your controller that inherits from the master one you call this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Api/Alumno/Search")]
public dynamic Search(string codigo, string nombre, string estado, int? curso, int? paralelo)
{    
    return ResponseOk<dynamic>(result);
}
```

---

For all your non controlled exceptions you can have an action filter and manage them

```
public class ErrorLoggingFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //Exception
    }
}
```